# scalajs-react: sending child component currrent state of information

Tags: reactjs, scalajs-react

I have a child component sitting inside a parent component. Parent component has some information, say I, which keeps changing based on user actions. In child component I have a button, and I want to change state of this button based on current value of I.

What is idiomatic way of doing it in scalajs-react/React?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it via props and optionally use [`Reusability`](https://github.com/japgolly/scalajs-react/blob/master/doc/PERFORMANCE.md#reusability) to prevent the child components from needlessly re-rendering too often.